RStudio/Quarto is unable to make a pdf because it can't find xelatex.fmt, which is in system path
RStudio/Quarto is unable to make a pdf because it can't find xelatex.fmt.

I've recently updated tlmgr and all LaTeX packages
I've also run fmtutil-sys --all
xelatex is in /c/texlive/2024/bin/windows/xelatex.exe
xelatex.fmt is in /c/texlive/2024/texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.fmt

Both paths are in both my personal "Path" and system "Path" environment variables.

More detail regarding the exact error message:

...\Peter\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:941:
...\Peter\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:864: no
appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
Running the command
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\fmtutil-user.exe
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!
updating tlmgr
updating existing packages
compilation failed- missing packages (automatic installation failed)

This message is unhelpful. I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt' would suggest that the parent directory of xelatex.fmt is not in the global system path, but I assure you it is. It is also in the personal system path.
This may also implicate tinytex, but tinytex has been shipping with RStudio since the times of Olduvai Gorge, so it would seem to be beyond reproach. But maybe it isn't?
The problem is not unique to Quatro. It fails for Rmd as well. The error is

The system cannot find the path specified.
Error in if (fig_crop) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls:  ... do.call ->  -> output_format -> knitr_options_pdf
Execution halted

Unhelpful.
I could include the content of log files, but there are 68 under c:\texlive/2024.
$ find . -name '*.log' -print
./install-tl.log
./temp/update-self.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/cweb-latex/examples/compare/wcltx.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex-web-companion/ch2/latexexa.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/latex-web-companion/ch4/latexexa.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-umlsd/demo/customize.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-umlsd/demo/postlevel.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgf-umlsd/demo/threadbias.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/pst-eucl-translation-bg/Exemples/arc_in.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/regstats/regstats-example.log
./texmf-dist/doc/latex/skeyval/skeyval-view-pokayoke1.log
./texmf-var/web2c/aleph/aleph.log
./texmf-var/web2c/euptex/eptex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/euptex/euptex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/euptex/platex-dev.log
./texmf-var/web2c/euptex/platex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/euptex/ptex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/euptex/uplatex-dev.log
./texmf-var/web2c/euptex/uplatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/euptex/uptex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/hitex/hilatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/hitex/hitex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/luahbtex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/lualatex-dev.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luahbtex/lualatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luajithbtex/luajithbtex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luajittex/luajittex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luatex/dvilualatex-dev.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luatex/dvilualatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luatex/dviluatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luatex/luacsplain.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luatex/luatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luatex/optex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/luatex/pdfcsplain.log
./texmf-var/web2c/metafont/mf.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/amstex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/cont-en.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/csplain.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/eplain.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/etex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/jadetex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex-dev.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/mex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/mllatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/mltex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/mptopdf.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfcsplain.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfetex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfjadetex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex-dev.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfmex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdftex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfxmltex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/texsis.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/utf8mex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/xmltex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/tex/lollipop.log
./texmf-var/web2c/tex/tex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
./texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
./texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log
./texmf-var/web2c/xetex/cont-en.log
./texmf-var/web2c/xetex/pdfcsplain.log
./texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex-dev.log
./texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xelatex.log
./texmf-var/web2c/xetex/xetex.log
Should the permissions be 777 for all of these log files?
Are there any log files you'd like to see?
I'm using RStudio 2024.04.0 Build 735, and
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=xelatex) restricted \write18 enabled.

I'm happy to add some symbolic links, but before I do, I should ask here
a) am I on the right track?
b) which symbolic links would you add?

without seeing the logs impossible really to help, do you have two tex installed are you sure the tl2024 version is being called?

It would stand to reason that log files would be created, but they aren't -- at least, not in the work directory where one would be inclined to look for them. If I run a cygwin/unix find command to local all .log files under /c/texlive/2024, I find none under ./bin/windows and 57 under texmf-var. Xelatex.log has 1770 lines of housekeeping. The only reference to fmt is the line "Beginning to dump on file xelatex.fmt" - which is a) unhelpful and b) captures the spirit of the moment exactly. ;) This seems like a path problem, which is why I am ready to edit paths and/or crisscross with symlinks.

But thank you for responding just the same. I'm running Windows 11, XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=xelatex)
restricted \write18 enabled. RStudio = 2024.04.0 Build 735. And I took the liberty of changing the permission of xelatex.fmt from 770 to 777 because, you know, it could be that, too! (But it wasn't.)

That log shows related format preloaded do found, my suspicion is the failed run was using the tinytex that comes with r not texlive 2024

I think I had  a similar issue in Linux after being sure of remove  tynitex and install vanilla TL 2024, After try everything except hammering the stupid computer, I think that the solution was tlmgr install --reinstall xetex. This install not only xetex but some other basic packages  and run mktexlsr, updmap-sys and  fmtutil-sys.

Thank you for your response, Fran. I tried your command, which executed without any problems, but the failure persists: Running the command C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\fmtutil-user.exe
I can't find the format file `xelatex.fmt'!
updating tlmgr
updating existing packages
compilation failed- missing packages (automatic installation failed)

@DavidCarlisle, I've just posted the last few lines of the error message in the last comment. Yes, it seems to be using tinytex. If I turn off tinytex as RStudio->Tools->GlobalOptions->Sweave->TinyText=unchecked, the effect is . . . nothing at all. Tinytex is still implicated in the final error. Noting also that RStudio->Tools->Project Options->Sweave or -> Knitr also fail in the same manner.

Can you double-check you can compile a simple hello, world! tex file at the command line (or whatever it is called)? Try with xelatex or xetex, depending on your file. Then you could at least rule out any issues on that side. With the caveat that I know zilch about Windows, I'd be very surprised if your log files are being created in the TL tree. You shouldn't need write permission to that tree when compiling normally. The log files all look like perfectly normal files from use of tlmgr. I have 67 in my tree and I know I'm not writing there when I compile documents because I can't.

So as expected, you are not using texlive 2024, which has xelatex, but tiny tex so you need to uninstall that or make sure texlive is ahead of tinytex on the path

@PeterLeopold, As David pointed out, your comment demonstrates that you are running the fmtutil-user installed by TinyTeX. TinyTeX is based in TeX Live, so it has xelatex and all the other TL tools, but expect things on different paths and maybe with different versions! Mixing both is a bad idea. The first thing to do is clarify what hairy beast is biting you: Chack that you really uninstall TinyTeX,  no just "tinytex" (the R package), but also TinyTeX (the latex distro) completely. See here.

This worked:
Since all errors pointed to texlive, I decided to run the uninstaller. But there isn't one!?! Yikes! Fortunately, I can bush-whack my way through a manual uninstall:

I deleted c:\texlive.
I removed all reference to texlive from the system and user-specific environment variable PATH.
I inspected the Windows registry and didn't find an references to texlive.
I reinstalled tinytex using the standard RStudio-recommended protocol.
(I didn't need to reboot.)

And then everything worked fine.
The culprit was pre-modern distribution of texlive. It confounded and/or was confounded by tinytex.
